# How to turn-off NextJS hot module replacement warnings

Tags: react, typescript, nextjs

I'm just starting out with the Next.js framework, and I can't find any information on how to turn off the repetitive warnings caused by hot reloading a modified page:

`This may have been caused by live reload or hot module replacement in which case it can be safely ignored. Make sure to test your application with a production build as repeat registrations will throw in production.`

It's pretty annoying that this message completely floods the debug console/terminal, making it difficult to see other warnings and errors.

I tried googling some switches, but without success. Is there any way to turn off these messages?

Thanks

All message log:

```
'CustomElementRegistry' already has "w3m-connecting-wc-desktop" defined. This may have been caused by live reload or hot module replacement in which case it can be safely ignored.
Make sure to test your application with a production build as repeat registrations will throw in production.
index.js:102
'CustomElementRegistry' already has "w3m-connecting-wc-injected" defined. This may have been caused by live reload or hot module replacement in which case it can be safely ignored.
Make sure to test your application with a production build as repeat registrations will throw in production.
index.js:102
'CustomElementRegistry' already has "w3m-connecting-wc-mobile" defined. This may have been caused by live reload or hot module replacement in which case it can be safely ignored.
Make sure to test your application with a production build as repeat registrations will throw in production.
index.js:102
'CustomElementRegistry' already has "w3m-connecting-wc-qrcode" defined. This may have been caused by live reload or hot module replacement in which case it can be safely ignored.
Make sure to test your application with a production build as repeat registrations will throw in production.
index.js:102
'CustomElementRegistry' already has "w3m-connecting-wc-unsupported" defined. This may have been caused by live reload or hot module replacement in which case it can be safely ignored.
Make sure to test your application with a production build as repeat registrations will throw in production.
index.js:102
'CustomElementRegistry' already has "w3m-connecting-wc-web" defined. This may have been caused by live reload or hot module replacement in which case it can be safely ignored.
Make sure to test your application with a production build as repeat registrations will throw in production.
index.js:102
'CustomElementRegistry' already has "w3m-header" defined. This may have been caused by live reload or hot module replacement in which case it can be safely ignored.
Make sure to test your application with a production build as repeat registrations will throw in production.
```